# How to indicate insertion of a new record into table with pagination

Tags: tables, input, indicator

I'm looking for a way to indicate successful addition of new record to table.

I have two main elements on my page - a form used to add new records and, below, a table displaying all the existing records. The table is sorted alphabetically and paginated.

When a user adds a new record I need to indicate that it was saved and entered into the table but if the new record's sort order in the table would not place it in view, how should I indicate that the entry was successful? And should I refresh the table to show the range of results that contain the new entry?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A green "Record was added successfully" message at the top after the user has clicked "Add Author". This will give the user peace of mind. Something [like this.](https://www.siteground.com/img/knox/tutorials/uploaded_images/images/cpanelgoogleapps/googleapps10.jpg)

It would be best to refresh the table as this happens. Otherwise the user may attempt to add the same record again, causing duplicates. You can use something like the Yellow Fade Technique which [37signals popularised.](https://signalvnoise.com/archives/000558.php)

Comment: Thanks @philip - I'll probably use add a success message right next to the Add Author button. The bigger problem is *how* to refresh the table and display the new record. What if the table flows off the bottom of the screen? Do I scroll to it and risk the user missing the success message? Is it reasonable to scroll the page to show the new record? What if the user wants to enter a few records one after the other?

Comment: You could consider putting the "New Author" form into a modal. Then when they click "Add Author" you can close the modal and you won't have to worry about scrolling as the table will be the only thing on the page. Then as suggested, use the yellow fade technique to temporarily highlight the new record.

Comment: It is not necessary to show the new record if it will be inserted on page 2+. If it's on the first page, use the yellow fade technique. If there are multiple authors, change the green success from "Author added successfully" to "2 authors added successfully" when the 2nd author is inserted.